# Use javascript to crop image

Tags: javascript

I want to put a sprite image in my website, and use javascript to crop it to many separate images, then put these images into an image array.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: You can always "fake" a crop with CSS/img elements and overflows. It would be one image (and should thus be shared in memory, not duplicated, so not so bad as it sounds :-), but each "view" would crop appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html), if you're using jQuery or [JavaScript Image Cropper UI](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/) if you're using prototype.

What server-side language are you using? If you just want a straight crop w/o the graphical interface it might be better to do it server side.

If you're using PHP, check out this [tutorial on nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/)

If you're using Ruby on Rails, check out [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: I want the website to automatically crop image after user connected it, not let user crop. Can this plug-in do this? Thanks!!

Comment: @Sam, that's why I am asking you what server-side language you are using. It would be better to do this server-side. I updated my answer to include a few suggestions for different languages.